# Rails - images with Redcarpet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcarpet

I'm writing a Rails application and have articles in Markdown rendered using the Redcarpet gem. I would like to include images in my articles, how would I go about doing this? Where is the correct place for the images in my application, and how would I display them from that location using markdown?

Also, if I wanted the user to be able to attach/embed an image in their article, how would I do this?

By the way, I'm using Rails 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the same as regular markdown. You use the following syntax:

```
![alt text](image_path_or_url)
```

This will compile to:

`<img src='<path_or_url'> alt="alt text">`

If the image src is a url, nothing else is necessary.

If it's a local image, you need to ensure it's accessible at the path you provided.

In Rails, the `public/` directory is available as static assets in development. In production, you'd need to set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `app/config/environments/production.rb`

So for example if you had an image at `public/test.jpg` then you could use this markdown:

```
![test image](./test.jpg)
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. How would I enable user upload to the public directory? And when would I put images in app/assets/images instead of public/images?

Comment: I don't personally use app/assets/images, so I'm not sure how that works. To enable user upload probably use some gem such as carrierwave or paperclip

Answer (score 2):

This tripped me up also. Here's the syntax to use images stored in `app/assets/images`

```
 ![test](/assets/test.jpg)
```

So just remove the `/images` (this applies elsewhere when using images in rails).

You can also input html directly in markdown:

```
 <img src="/assets/test.jpg" />
```